# How to authenticate with the admin user when using kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I created a cluster with kubeadm (well it's just a single node / master for now) however I seem to be having issues with authenticating as the admin user.

```
KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf kubectl get sa
No resources found.
Error from server (Forbidden): serviceaccounts is forbidden: User "system:node:osboxes" cannot list serviceaccounts in the namespace "default": disabled by feature gate TokenRequest
```

I'm assuming that is the admin user? If not, where can I find it / authenticate with it?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: `export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`